# android can't get photo uri from db cursor

Tags: android

I am storing contact photos in db but when I want to load those photos to imageview, i am getting error:

```
The method setImageURI(Uri) in the type ImageView is not applicable
for the arguments (String)
```

Here is the call to `setImageURI` inside a class that extends `CursorAdapter` in order to show contact photos in listview:

```
photoView.setImageURI(cursor.getString(3));
```

I also tried type caste string to uri but that isn't allowed either:

```
photoView.setImageURI((Uri) cursor.getString(3));
```

How do I load photo from cursor into imageview ? Thanks

Comment: Convert the string to Uri.

Comment: @AstralProjection: It doesn't work, I already tried to cast string to uri

Comment: Try the code I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
    String mUri = cursor.getString(3)
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(mUri);
    photoView.setImageURI((myUri)
```

Comment: Oops didn't know it was this easy, thanks :) will accept this answer :)

Comment: Yes its very simple, a Google search would have given you the desired result. Make a habit of searching on Google first. Lot of people face similar problems. Cheers, happy coding :)